# Creating a new voice for Alexa within my skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, voice, assistant

Is it possible to change the voice alexa is using within my skill?

i.e. the user asks

> Alexa Ask Car Washing when the next available appointment is?

and have Alexa respond with a voice that matches my carwashing brand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, it is possible.**

You can use **SSML Tags** in output speech response of your skill to achieve this.

You can

- whisper
- put emphasis on a word or phrase
- use different languages like French, Spanish etc.
- different voices and many more

For Example

```html
<speak>
    Here's a surprise you did not expect.  
    <voice name="Kendra"><lang xml:lang="en-US">I want to tell you a secret.</lang></voice>
    <voice name="Brian"><lang xml:lang="en-GB">Your secret is safe with me!</lang></voice> 
    <voice name="Kendra"><lang xml:lang="en-US">I am not a real human.</lang></voice>.
    Can you believe it?
</speak>
```

Learn more about Using SSML Tags [**HERE**](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference.html)

Comment: or add a MP3 file with your brand recording like this in SSML - `<audio src="soundbank://soundlibrary/transportation/amzn_sfx_car_accelerate_01" />`